# Editar un usuario sin requerir ingresar y confirmar contraseña Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo generado con devise un tipo de usuario, bien, he creado un administrador personal el cual llamo por modal usando ajax el form para editar los usuarios, pero como he tenido problemas para llamar al form de usuario de devise, genere por aparte un controller normal con el mismo nombre del recurso de devise, donde se me hace mas fácil controlar el código, pero cuando hago edit, y actualizo, requiere de una contraseña y la confirme, como si estuviera registrando y no actualizando, espero puedan ayudarme, aquí mi código:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">

    <div class="callout border">
      <h6>Registro de asesores</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="callout border">

      <%= form_for @advisor, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
      <% if @advisor.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@advisor.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this @advisor from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @advisor.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-6 columns">
            <%= f.label :nombre %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Nombre", required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="small-6 columns">
            <%= f.label :correo_electronico %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Correo electronico", required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-6 columns">
            <%= f.label :contraseña %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="small-6 columns">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 columns">
            <%= f.label :logo_representativo_de_la_empresa %>
            <div class="input-group">
              <%= f.text_field :image, disabled: true, class: "input-group-field" %>
              <div class="input-group-button">
                <label for="exampleFileUpload" class="button">Imagen</label>
                <%= f.file_field :image, id: "exampleFileUpload", class: "show-for-sr" %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    <br>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 columns">
            <%= f.label :acerca_de %>
            <%= f.text_area :about, placeholder: "Acerca de", :rows => 4, :cols => 120, required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 columns">
            <%= f.label :admin %>
            <%= f.check_box :admin %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 columns">
            <%= f.submit "Guardar", class: "button" %>
          </div>
        </div>

      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**advisors_controller.rb**

```
class AdvisorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_advisor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @advisor = Advisor.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @advisor = Advisor.new(advisor_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @advisor.save
        format.html { redirect_to @advisor, notice: 'advisor was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @advisor }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @advisor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @advisor.update(advisor_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @advisor, notice: 'advisor was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @advisor }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @advisor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @advisor.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, notice: 'El municipio se ha eliminado' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_advisor
      @advisor = Advisor.find(params[:id])
    end

    def advisor_params
      params.require(:advisor).permit(:name, :image, :about, :admin)
    end
end
```

**link_edit**

```
<%= link_to "Editar", edit_advisor_path(advisor), remote: true, :data => { :open => 'exampleModal1' }, class: "button blue" %>
```

Comment: primero que todo no es recomendable que un administrador cambie la contraseña de un usuario. Segundo te recomiendo que tengas 2 formularios distintos, no para la información del usuario y el otro para el cambio de contraseña. Incuso podrías probar el eliminar los input de contraseña (los 2 campos) y creo que con eso puede editar la información del usuario.

Comment: Hola inye!  A eso voy, y efectivamente el admin no puede editarlo, y esten o no esten los campos requiere los campos y eso es debido a devise q los requiere pero no se como decirle al modelo que nos los requiera en edit

Comment: a q url se postea tu EDIT al presionar `Editar`? (en mis aplicaciones con devise yo no tengo problemas en modificar datos de usuarios)

Comment: Hola Inye, no me refiero a la edicion individual que cada usuario puede hacer con edit_user_registration_path, me refiero a mi controller generado propiamente que para editar el usuario de la BD seria con edit_user_path, ya coloco unas imagenes

Comment: puedes colocar el error exacto que te tira?